# Spring Boot find beans in web application context

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How do we find all the beans in web application context of web application build using spring Boot. I have seen many examples to get beans from application context but not from web application context.

Answer (score 0):

Auto wire application context,

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

And access the beans,

```
String[] beans = appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    
for (String bean : beans) {
    System.out.println(bean);
}
```

Comment: As I said I would like to find the bean in the web application context not from app context